# Excel: Worksheet events not working at all

Tags: excel, vba, events

I am currently trying to get a certain value in a cell depending on a other value in a cell using events in VBA. I am currently working on a excel project where I need to use this, but it is not working at all. I have tried everything. The strange thing is that when I open a new excel it works perfectly fine but not with my current excel file. Why is this?

This is what I tried so far:

1. File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Macro Settings -> "Trust access to the VBA project object model" is selected. Save the file.
2. I also have ensured Application.EnableEvents = True using CTRL + G

I searched the whole internet for this problem but couldn't find a solution. It is just the problem with this specific excel file.

This is an example of a code I used to test if the events even get triggered:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "selected " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

Ofcourse it is placed in the sheet code and not in a seperate macro.

Comment: Seach for `Application.EnableEvents` everywhere in the workbook Doyou find it anywhere?

Comment: Hi, I searched the whole project with no results.. I can send you the file if you want

Comment: Sure I would like to test it. Can you upload it on www.wikisend.com and share it here?

Comment: Which sheet are you checking for the event? it is working for me in Verkoop

Comment: I was actually checking it in Verkoop. Why doesn't it work for me then??

Comment: umm, macros are enabled right? What if you copy that code to some other sheet, does it work on those sheets?

Comment: No, it does not work on any sheet. I have no idea how this happens because on every new excel file I open it just works perfectly fine.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. On 'Mutaties' it does actually work. But the rest not.

Comment: Then I guess there is something wrong with yuor ActiveX controls. Delete them and use Form controls and try again?

Comment: I think I just create a new sheet and just copy everything. Hope that works.